# (Cauchy) complete metric spaces in enriched category theory

Tags: metric-spaces, category-theory, complete-spaces, enriched-category-theory

A [Lawvere metric space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metric+space#LawvereMetricSpace) is Cauchy complete iff it is [Cauchy complete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category) regarded as a $[0,\infty]$-enriched category. I have two questions about this observation:

- Is Cauchy completeness (in the setting of enriched category theory) equivalent to the existence of some type of (weighted) limits of colimits?
- Which Lawvere metric spaces are complete (resp. cocomplete) as enriched categories?

Comment: Perhaps better in overflow?

Comment: I was under the impression that Cauchy-completeness means "absolute colimits exist".

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes I read this on the nlab page, but there it is only mentioned for ordinary categories.

Comment: @PaulFrost Perhaps. But on the other hand, I think these are very "elementary" questions which can be answered by anyone who really knows the notion of Cauchy completion for enriched categories. I really only dabbled into this, and hoped that someone can give me a shortcut to find this out, to be honest, instead of reading the whole relevant literature (this is what I would do before posting on MO).

Comment: I think it is also correct for enriched categories. There is a characterisation of absolute colimits in terms of profunctors with adjoints too, but there are some details in between to be filled in.

Comment: I suspect the answer to question 1 is yes: maybe one can adapt the remark in "[Flexible limits](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82151786.pdf)", page 3, and express Cauchy completeness as a limit on a similar shape?

Comment: I'm confused what the first question is asking. Cauchy completeness for enriched categories is by definition admitting absolute weighted (co)limits, and this is the notion used to characterise Cauchy completeness of Lawvere metric spaces. How are you defining Cauchy completeness in your question?

Comment: @varkor I use the definition in the linked nlab page. But all your comments then already answer Q1.

Comment: I posted a too-quick answer to Q2, but just to note what I do have: $x\sqcup y$ in a metric space satisfies $d(x,x\sqcup y)=d(y,x\sqcup y)=0$ and $d(x\sqcup y,z)=\max(d(x,z),d(y,z))$; the first property shows (co)products are only going to occur nontrivially in an asymmetric metric space, such as a poset (equipped with length $0$ for every arrow and other lengths $\infty.$)

Comment: The existence of tensors seems even harder to satisfy: we have to have $d(r\otimes x,y)=\max(r-d(x,y),0)$ for $r\in[0,\infty]$ and all $y,$ so you're simultaneously moving $x$ closer to all points that are more than $r$ away. If you have, say, an equilateral triangle of sidelength $1$ in $X,$ then you can't tensor any of its vertices by any number in $(1/2,1),$ since there's no point simultaneously at distance less than $1/2$ from two points at distance $1.$ So admitting tensors seems to mean your metric space is basically 1-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't it be + instead of max?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't think so; the max expression should be $d(x,y)^r,$ the internal hom in $[0,\infty],$ which is truncated subtraction. I may have the sign of the difference flipped, though. All this asymmetry is crazy when you dig into it!

Comment: In particular, the asymmetry explains why my argument in my previous comment doesn't show as much as it seems to: it's possible to have $d(x,y)+d(x,z)<d(y,z)$ in an asymmetric metric space, which allows for the cocompleteness of presheaf metric spaces–function spaces with the sup norm–but only before symmetrizing! Indeed the "dimensionality" of a nontrivially directed metric space seems not to behave in a very intuitive way at all.